# How to get the errror body sent from server from retrofit authenticator in android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, authenticator

I am using Retrofit for API calls in one of android project.
I want to read the error message sent from backend for any API when token gets expired. When token gets expired OkHttpClient.authenticator gets called with Response object. In this authenticator I have to read the error message sent from my backend to differentiate the errors.
But I don't see any way to read the error message sent from server from Response object.
Any one have any idea how to read this?

Answer (score 0):

You can take Unauthorize response body from authenticate function parameter response variable.

```
override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
    val unAuthMessage = response.body?.string()
    //Your code...

}
```

For my situation, my body is just string but if your message is json, you can convert to json object.